# Get power for driver circuitry in an inverter

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, boost, ups

Planning to build an inverter based on egs002, I got high voltage high frequency side (ferrite core transformer including N-MOS and high speed rectifier) from old UPS board which I will drive using SG3525

UPS used UC3843 and a its own transformer to create power for driving gates of high voltage FET and other components that require 5VDC to 15VDC, that circuit was removed by someone and I don't see myself competent enough to recreate that.

**Main 12VDC to 350VDC**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3eqpJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I have different options in mind but most seem to create a failure point in my design

- **use boost converter like mt3608 to create 18V, then use regulators like 7815, 7812 and 7805**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk3Gmp.png)</sup>

- **build small transformer with primary connected to output of high power main transformer to convert ~230VAC back to ~20VAC, again use regulators**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiu0AU.png)</sup>

- **use battery to get 5VDC to drive driver board (egs002), only use boost converter for gate driving voltages (through 7815 or 7812)**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0dsFa.png)</sup>

- **create my own boost converter based on SG3525 or UC3843 and use different loops for 18VAC (then 7815 or 7812) and 10VAC (then use a 7805)**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpz8Z.png)</sup>

**Image of UPS Board**
[image: UPS BOARD]

Which route is a good balance between ease and reliability?

Comment: Please post a schematic.

Comment: @winny posted schematics, please don't mind the mess